# python pip required Build tools while it is already install

Tags: python, pip, build-tools

I've seen this question has been posted many times, and people manage to solve the problem, but I don't !!

OS Version :

```
Windows 10 21H1 Build 19043.1288
```

Python version :

```
Python 3.9.7 (tags/v3.9.7:1016ef3, Aug 30 2021, 20:19:38) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
```

Pip, wheel and setuptool are up to date :

```
>python -m pip install --upgrade pip
Requirement already satisfied: pip in c:\users\[...]\python39\lib\site-packages (21.3.1)

>pip install --upgrade wheel
Requirement already satisfied: wheel in c:\users\[...]\python39\lib\site-packages (0.37.0)

>pip install --upgrade setuptools
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\users\[...]\python39\lib\site-packages (58.5.3)
```

I've installed Visual build tools from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/ : vs_BuildTools.exe

I've tried both through the interface and command line :

```
>vs_buildtools.exe --norestart --passive --downloadThenInstall --includeRecommended --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools
```

And this is the .vsconfig file content from this installation :

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "components": [
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.Compiler",
    "Microsoft.Component.MSBuild",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreBuildTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.MSBuildTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CoreBuildTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Redist.14.Latest",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.19041",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CMake.Project",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TestTools.BuildTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ASAN",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TextTemplating",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CoreIde",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.NativeDesktop.Core",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.v141.x86.x64",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools"
  ]
}
```

I've also tried to install Visual Studio Community 2017 (I've already had it installed actually), and this is the .vsconfig file from this install:

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "components": [
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.CoreEditor",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.Compiler",
    "Microsoft.Component.MSBuild",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Static.Analysis.Tools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Roslyn.LanguageServices",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.TextTemplating",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Debugger.JustInTime",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.NuGet",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.4.7.1.TargetingPack",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.WebToolsExtensions",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CoreIde",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Redist.14.Latest",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentGroup.NativeDesktop.Core",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.Tools.x86.x64",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Graphics.Win81",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Graphics.Tools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.DiagnosticTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.17763",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.CMake.Project",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.ATL",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.TestAdapterForBoostTest",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.TestAdapterForGoogleTest",
    "Microsoft.Component.VC.Runtime.UCRTSDK",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows81SDK",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.16299.UWP",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.16299.UWP.Native",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.16299.Desktop",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.VC.140",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.NativeDesktop",
    "Microsoft.Net.Component.3.5.DeveloperTools",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Unity",
    "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedGame"
  ]
}
```

I've restarted my computer and .... :

```
>pip install box2d-py
Collecting box2d-py
  Using cached box2d-py-2.3.8.tar.gz (374 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: box2d-py
  Building wheel for box2d-py (setup.py) ... \

[...]

    Box2D\Common\b2Settings.h(144) : Warning 506: Can't wrap varargs with keyword arguments enabled
    Box2D\Common\b2Math.h(91) : Warning 509: Overloaded method b2Vec2::operator ()(int32) effectively ignored,
    Box2D\Common\b2Math.h(85) : Warning 509: as it is shadowed by b2Vec2::operator ()(int32) const.
    error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

I'm going nuts !!!

What's wrong with this process ?

Please Help Needed.

Thanks a lot !

Note : I've also tried to add cl.exe directory to my path and it's working.

```
>cl
Compilateur d'optimisation Microsoft (R) C/C++ version 19.16.27045 pour x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Tous droits réservés.

utilisation : cl [ option... ] nom de fichier... [ /link linkoption... ]
```

But still have same error on pip install....